# Building an array of sequential numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

i have an incoming array:

```
[{step: 0, count: 1}, {step: 1, count: 5}, {step: 5, count: 5}]
```

so i need to transform incoming array in another array

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```

I have tried to go this way:

```js
const convertRangeData = (rangeData) =>
  {
  const convertedRangeData =
    rangeData.reduce( (acc, item) => 
        {
        const { step, count } = item;
        const prev                 = acc[acc.length - 1];
        return [...acc, ...[...Array(count)].fill(step).map((i, idx) => i * (idx + 1) + prev)];
        },[0] )
    return convertedRangeData;
  }
```

but I've got

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
```

Comment: I've updated my answer after seeing your code to support ranges starting with the previous number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.from()` to create an array with values in the ranges. Then iterate the array of ranges.

To create the continuous ranges reduce the array of `ranges`. When creating a range take the last number from the accumulator (`acc`), and use it as the start value.

```js
const range = ({ step, count }, start = 0) => 
  Array.from({ length: count }, (_, i) => (i + 1) * step + start)
  
const continuousRange = arr =>
  arr.reduce((acc, r) => acc.concat(range(r, acc[acc.length -1])), [])

const ranges = [{step: 0, count: 1}, {step: 1, count: 5}, {step: 5, count: 5}]

const result = continuousRange(ranges)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Your solution is exactly what i've looked for!

Answer (score 0):

my way

```js
const ranges = [{step: 0, count: 1}, {step: 1, count: 5}, {step: 5, count: 5}] 

const convertRangeData = rangeData => rangeData.reduce((acc, {step,count}) =>
  {
  let prev = acc[acc.length - 1] || 0
  while(count--)
    acc.push(prev+=step)  
  return acc
  },[])

console.log( convertRangeData(ranges) )
```